# How can I eliminate the line feeds at the end of the items returned by file()?

Tags: php, file

I have a text file which has got several names in it example:

```
mathew
james
kelvin
peter
jackson
linak
thomas
```

the main code is given below:

```
 $names = file(names.txt);

    foreach ( $names as $name) {

    //then this call to a function 

    $data = 'localhost/q?detail='.$name;

    //////do some code etc..

    //insert into table
     }
```

my problem is it calls like `localhost/q?detail=mathew%0A`
and next `localhost/q?detail==%0D%0A` and next `localhost/q?detail=james%0A`

How do I get rid of those `%0D%0A` things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are line terminators (or separators; depending on how you look at it) and are included by default in the items returned by `file()`, as the documentation states:

> Returns the file in an array. Each element of the array corresponds to a line in the file, with the newline still attached.
>
> —[*PHP documentation: file*](http://php.net/file)

To remove them, simply pass the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag to `file()`:

> **`FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`**
>
> Do not add newline at the end of each array element

So in your code just do the following:

```
$names = file('names.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Comment: what you said is correct for first name and it is without special charater...but from next onwards it is coming blank!!! no name it is taking..why??

Comment: yes I got it you need to add FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES then it will work